# Setting up honeynet behind DSL router

Tags: virtualization, router, dmz

[image]

I have setup double honeynet for capturing polymorphic worms as shown in the figure.

The whole setup is in Virtual environment on a single host. I want all the traffic to reach the internal router so that it can be further sent to the honeynet for further processing. Also, I have a web server shown in the figure that is running using port forwarding in DSL router.

I want all the traffic, including that of web server, to reach the local router (local router is software router implemented with iptables) so that local router sends web traffic to web server and the rest to honeynet.

I want to know how to achieve this. I was thinking we can make the local router a DMZ host on the DSL router. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Even though you want to do this to direct traffic to a honeynet, this is not a security question but a networking question.

Comment: your diagram is unnecessarily confusing (why did you include the "other machines"? why didn't you use a hierarchical model?) - all you need to do is to move the router in front of the switch -   one port to the bridge, the other port to your internal networks - and do all the routing work on the router

Comment: DSL router has minimum capabilities. You cannot add rules to router. Do you mean I need to add static routes ?. I cannot move router in front of switch because switch is virtual which is created by vmware workstation. Also I am getting internet through DSL router.